# How to set default root category on a store while creating it programatically?

Tags: category, stores

I want to set a category on the new stores I'm creating, but could not find any appropriate method.

```
    public function  createStore()
    {
        // load default website
        $defaultWebId = $this->defaultWebsite->load(self::DEFAULT_WEB_ID);

        // create german store
        $germanStore = $this->storeFactory->create();
        $germanStore->setWebsite($defaultWebId);
        $germanStore->setName("germanStore");
        $germanStore->setCode("Task5German");

        // create english store
        $englishStore = $this->storeFactory->create();
        $englishStore->setWebsite($defaultWebId);
        $englishStore->setName("englishStore");
        $englishStore->setCode("Task5English");
    }
```

I want to set a "default root category" on both of these stores. By default root category, I mean this: [image]
Any kind of help would be appreciated

Update:

```
public function createStores()
    {
        // load default website
        $defaultWebId = $this->defaultWebsite->load(self::DEFAULT_WEB_ID);

        // create english group
        $englishGroup = $this->groupFactory->create();
        $englishGroup->setName("englishGroup");
        $englishGroup->setCode("Task5EnglishGroup");
        $englishGroup->setWebsite($defaultWebId);
        $englishGroup->setRootCategoryId(self::DEFAULT_ROOT_CATEGORY);
        
        // create german group 
        $germanGroup = $this->groupFactory->create();
        $germanGroup->setName("germanGroup");
        $germanGroup->setCode("Task5EnglishGroup");
        $germanGroup->setWebsite($this->defaultWebsite);
        $germanGroup->setRootCategoryId(self::DEFAULT_ROOT_CATEGORY);
        
        // create german store view
        $germanStore = $this->storeFactory->create();
        $germanStore->setName("germanStore");
        $germanStore->setCode("Task5German");
        $germanStore->setGroup($germanGroup);
        
        // create english store view
        $englishStore = $this->storeFactory->create();
        $englishStore->setName("englishStore");
        $englishStore->setCode("Task5EnglishStoreView");
        $englishStore->setGroup($englishGroup);
        try {
            $englishStore->setCurrentCurrencyCode("GBP");
        }
        catch (LocalizedException) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: ->setRootCategoryId(...)

Comment: @Marius There is no such method in the store class

Comment: ah, right. You cannot set a category id on a store view. you can only set it to a store group. and then you assign the store view to the store group. So you need to create a website, a store group that belongs to the website for which you attach the category  id and a store view that belongs to the store group

Comment: @Marius I though storeFactory created stores and not store views, I will try your solution now

Comment: Try with \Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory to create store groups...and just for the record ...store view and store are kind of the same thing